# How to track my movements with BLE?

Tags: discussion

I doubt that this is on topic, or that I can make it so, in order to get  an answer on our main site (can I?). please note that I am not looking for an answer here in Meta.

Basically, I want to implement a tracking system, to track my movements around my house.

I will wear a BLE wristband and will position SBCs (maybe Orange Pi, I haven’t decided) at each doorway between two rooms to detect the wristband.

BLE is not a protocol that I know – what comes next? How does one of my door sensors know that my BLE wristband is passing it? Does it attempt to pair, or what?

I will handle all the higher level stuff, like the band being detected by two doorways at once – although I would welcome advice; do I detect which room I am in by signal strength, or by knowing which room I came out of?

I don’t even know where to start, so any advice would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking to ask whether the example question is on-topic and how it could be made so? If so maybe you could edit to clarify that you are not actually looking for an answer to the question itself on the meta site.

Comment: I have update the question and hopefully it is clearer now. I am not looking for an answer here, just a way to formulate this to make it on topic on the main site. Thanks for asking me to clarify (+1)